# How do we show the previous image in a picturebox in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net

I have stored the images in an array, after that, I have added an if statement to check which image is currently showing, here is my code so far but there are no results.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim img(3) As Image
        img(0) = My.Resources.bugs
        img(1) = My.Resources.discuss
        img(2) = My.Resources.flower
        img(3) = My.Resources.mask
        If PictureBox1.Image Is img(0) Then
            PictureBox1.Image = img(3)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a serious issue with your code. You should NOT access the same property of `My.Resources` over and over like that. That's because it extracts the data and creates a new object every time, so you will be creating four new `Image` objects every time the user clicks that `Button`. You should extract the resources and populate the array once only.

That's the reason that your `If` statement doesn't work. Even if they are created from the same resource, the `Image` object currently in the `PictureBox` is not the same object as is in your array.

You should store the index of the current image in a field and then, each time you want to go to the next image, you simply increment that field and get the `Image` at that index.  You can use `Mod` to wrap at the end of the array.

```
Private images As Image() = {My.Resources.bugs,
                             My.Resources.discuss,
                             My.Resources.flower,
                             My.Resources.mask}
Private imageIndex As Integer = 0

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    PictureBox1.Image = images(imageIndex)
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    imageIndex = (imageIndex + 1) Mod images.Length
    PictureBox1.Image = images(imageIndex)
End Sub
```

I missed that you said "previous" rather than "next".  This will work for that:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    imageIndex -= 1

    If imageIndex < 0 Then
        imageIndex = images.GetUpperBound(0)
    End If

    PictureBox1.Image = images(imageIndex)
End Sub
```